# Calling a Table Function in a loop to get a data dump

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, pipeline

I need to use a table function in the following scenario. I have a list of person_ids in one table and learning_path_ids in another table. So I want find whether any employees has completed any learning paths. For this I have a function called `Employees_Learning_Chk_f(person_I'd, learning_path_id)` which returns `1` or `0`. So by passing a `person_id` and a `learning_path_id`, I can find out whether that person has completed that learning path or not. I need to find this for all employees in the organization to get data dump. Problem is we have 9000 employees and 250 learning paths. So I have to run the above function in a loop by passing all person_id : learning_path_id combinations to get the final output for a data dump.

**Please not that the relation ship between person ids and learning paths is discarded here as we need historical information as well (Not only the details relevant for the current relationships as employees might had different relationships with the learning paths earlier).**

Following is the my approach.

```
--Defining types required.
CREATE TYPE tf_row AS OBJECT (
  person_id           NUMBER,
  learning_path_id    NUMBER,
  completion_status   NUMBER,
);
/

CREATE TYPE tf__tab IS TABLE OF tf_row;
/

-- Build the table function.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_completion_status (person_id IN NUMBER) RETURN tf_tab AS
  l_tab  tf_tab := tf_tab();
  status_flag number;
  --Getting all learning path IDs using a cursor.
  cursor c1 is
     SELECT distinct learning_path_id 
     FROM learning_paths;

BEGIN

   FOR learnings in c1
   LOOP
   --Calling an existing function which returns 1 if the employee
   --holding this person_id has completed the learning path related to 
   --this learning_path_id.
   select Employees_Learning_Chk_f(person_id, learnings.learning_path_id) 
   into status_flag
   From Dual;

   --If the learning path has been completed, the information is 
   --inserted to in memory table.
   If dual = 1 then
   l_tab.extend;
   l_tab(l_tab.last) := tf_row(person_id, learnings.learning_path_id, status_flag);
   end if;

   END LOOP;

   RETURN l_tab;
END;
```

Now I can call the above function by passing a person_id as follows...

```
select from table (get_completion_status(123456));
```

Output would be like this:

[image]

But I need to get the output for all 9000 employees in a similar manner. How this is possible? Is it possible to use PIPELINED feature? If yes, could you please explain how?

**Note:** 
I'm not allowed to create any tables even temporarily in the database with regard to this.

I'm using Oracle-SQL Developer connecting to a Oracle 11g database.

Comment: Can't you just do an outer join to your learning_paths table to get what you want, without using a function?

Comment: @Mark Leiber, I can't have a relationship between these two tables as I need to check whether a person has completed any learning paths out of those 250. so I have to pass a person_id together with all learning_path_ids one by one to the existing function "Employees_Learning_Chk_f(person_id, learning_path_id)" eventually 9000 x 250 calls to this function. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the definition of your existing tables?

Comment: @Mark Leiber, per_all_people_f (party_id, person_id, full_name, etc.)  ota_learning_paths(learning_path_id, creation_date, etc.) - this is a master table. http://oraclehrmsoverview.com/2014/12/16/oracle-learning-management-olm-tables/   Also pls note that "Employees_Learning_Chk_f" function checks the completion status of all courses coming under a learning path.

Comment: Do you know the definition of Employees_Learning_Chk_f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cartesian product (cross join) to do this in a single query:

```
select p.person_id, l.learning_path_id, Employees_Learning_Chk_f(p.person_id, l.learning_path_id) as status
from per_all_people_f p
cross join ota_learning_paths l;
```

If you can describe what Employees_Learning_Chk_f does, it can probably be eliminated too by adding another table to the query.